# Use OData $select to cherry pick fields from related object

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I'm using WebAPI 2.2 with OData V4.

It is possible for me to use `$filter=RelatedObj/PropertyName eq 'Some Value'` to filter a list of entities based on a related object property value.

However, when I try to use the same syntax with `$select`:

```
$select=Id,Name,RelatedObj/PropertyName
```

results in exception:

```
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Found a path with multiple navigation properties or a bad complex property path in a select clause. Please reword your query such that each level of select or expand only contains either TypeSegments or Properties.",
"innererror": {
"message": "Found a path with multiple navigation properties or a bad complex property path in a select clause. Please reword your query such that each level of select or expand only contains either TypeSegments or Properties.",
"type": "Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException",
```

Can this be solved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it using `$expand` and nested `$select` query option

```
$select=Id,Name&$expand=RelatedObj($select=PropertyName)
```

See the [ODATA documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398163)

Comment: This doesn't work for (some?) properties.  I get the error:  "Invalid $select properties."

I don't think the above syntax is supported for Microsoft Graph API (neither beta nor v1):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#query-parameter-limitations

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a `$select` on an item under a navigation property, you need to first `$expand` the navigation property.

```
EntitySet?$select=Id,Name,RelatedObj/PropertyName&$expand=RelatedObj
```